# Average part of a multidimensional array based on another array (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, average

```
B = randn(1,25,10);
Z = [1;1;1;2;2;3;4;4;4;3];
```

Ok, so, I want to find the locations where Z=1(or any numbers that are equal to each other), then average across each of the 25 points at these specific locations. In the example you would end with a 1*25*4 array.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I'm not the most versed in Matlab.

Comment: Why not `B = randn(10,25);`? But either way you can get started by creating a logical indexing vector like so: `Z == 1` to extract the correct `4` (although shouldn't it be `3`??) 'columns' in the 3rd dimension

Comment: Yeah, I could take out the first dimension. I just mocked up the problem. Z is not of size 10, it is more like 10,000, with maybe a 1000 unique values. I guess I could use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: break down the problem.

1. Define the groups (i.e. the set of unique Z values)
2. Find elements which belong to these groups
3. Take the average.

Once you have done that, you can begin to see it's a pretty standard for loop and "Select columns which meet criteria".

Something along the lines of:

```
B = randn(1,25,10);
Z = [1;1;1;2;2;3;4;4;4;3];

groups = unique(Z); %//find the set of groups
C = nan(1,25,length(groups)); %//predefine the output space for efficiency
for gi = 1:length(groups) %//for each group
  idx = Z == groups(gi); %//find it's members
  C(:,:,gi) = mean(B(:,:,idx), 3); %//select and mean across the third dimension
end
```

Comment: That looks like it will do the trick when I scale it up! Thanks a lot, Alan!

Comment: It should do.  While it may be tempting to try for an elegant single line solution, sometimes it's best to stick with a simple for-loop - particularly as matlab can optimize those itsself.  On a side note: if anyone can remind me how to get StackOverflow to recognize matlab format code I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If `B = randn(10,25);` then it's very easy because Matlab function usually works down the rows.

Using logical indexing:

```
ind = Z == 1;
mean(B(ind,:));
```

If you're dealing with multiple dimensions use `permute` (and `reshape` if you actually have 3 dimensions or more) to get yourself to a point where you're averaging down the rows as above:

```
B = randn(1,25,10);
BB = permute(B, [3,2,1])
```

continue as above